Getting Rquest has been Truncated error while uploading audio files using php
I am getting "request has been truncated" error when I upload 3 audios of 50MB each using php.
I have attached an image of the same.
enter image description here
Below are some of the variables which I have already set in the php.ini file :
upload_max_filesize =400M, max_input_vars =3000, max_input_time =60, max_execution_time =0, memory_limit =256M`
But I am still getting the "request has been truncated" error .  Any help me to resolve this issue will be appreciated. Thank you in advanced.
